# Using upsert-kafka with a flush buffer results in Null Pointer Exception

Tags: apache-flink

I have been trying to buffer output from the upsert-kafka connector using the documented parameters `sink.buffer-flush.max-rows` and `sink.buffer-flush.interval`

Whenever I attempt to run an INSERT query with buffering, I receive the following error (shortened for brevity):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.table.ReducingUpsertWriter.flush(ReducingUpsertWriter.java:145) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.table.ReducingUpsertWriter.lambda$registerFlush$3(ReducingUpsertWriter.java:124) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invokeProcessingTimeCallback(StreamTask.java:1693) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$null$22(StreamTask.java:1684) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:50) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsWhenDefaultActionUnavailable(MailboxProcessor.java:338) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:324) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:201) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:809) 
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:761) 
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958) 
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:937) 
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766) 
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

I have tried to dig into [the source code](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/98997ea37ba08eae0f9aa6dd34823238097d8e0d/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/ReducingUpsertWriter.java#L145) a bit at the indicated location from the exception, but I don't understand it well enough to know what is causing the NPE.  I am running Flink 1.14.3.  If I remove the buffering parameters from the table definition, everything works as expected (no errors).  Am I just doing something incorrectly or am I hitting a bug?  For reference, the table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE test_topic (
    `messageType` VARCHAR,
    `observationID` BIGINT,
    `obsYear` BIGINT,
    `obsMonth` BIGINT,
    `obsDay` BIGINT,
    `obsHour` BIGINT,
    `obsMinute` BIGINT,
    `obsTz` VARCHAR(5),
    `value` BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (observationID, messageType) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
    'key.format' = 'json',
    'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'brokers.example.com:9092',
    'sink.buffer-flush.max-rows' = '50000',
    'sink.buffer-flush.interval' = '1000',
    'topic' = 'test_topic',
    'value.format' = 'json'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It smells like a bug, especially since it works if you remove the buffer related parameters. I did a quick search in Flink's Jira ticket but I don't think there's a ticket already for this. The only one that mentions Upsert and NPEs is https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20825 but I don't think it's related.

Could you create one and provide as much details as possible there?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-25916.